# Set days since first occurrence based on multiple columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataset with this structure:

```
Date          datetime64[ns]
Events                 int64
Location              object
Day                  float64
```

I've used the following code to get the date of the first occurrence for location "A":

```
start_date = df[df['Location'] == 'A'][df.Events != 0].iat[0,0]
```

I now want to update all of the records after the start_date with the number of days since the start_date, where Day = df.Date - start_date.

I tried this code:

```
df.loc[df.Location == country, 'Day'] = (df.Date - start_date).days
```

However, that code returns an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'days'
```

The problem seems to be that the code recognizes df.Date as an object instead of a datetime. Anyone have any ideas on what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,  you need to add the [`.dt` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html#attributes).

```
df.loc[df.Location == country, 'Day'] = (df.Date - start_date).dt.days
```

Comment: Thank you, Scott. That did the trick. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Tim no problem.  Happy coding!

Comment: You can use something like `df['Day'] = np.where(df['Date'] > start_date, (df.Date - start_date).dtdays, df['Day'])`